# Delete a duplicate user from asp.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, asp.net-membership

For some reason, every once and a while, a user gets duplicated on registration in my asp.net web app. I don't know why (username is set as unique), but it gets through somehow and I end up with two exact users, except for the UserId that is auto-created. I can easily delete the user by username with `Membership.DeleteUser(User.Identity.Name)` but I don't want both to be deleted. I only want the duplicate. I can get the UserId (36 digits, perhaps it is a hash?) no problem, but how can I delete the user by that UserId? I haven't seen anything on UserId deletion method. Or, is it possible to delete just the duplicate another way (like take the second record of the username)?

As a side question, what can cause the duplicate when I have everything set not to allow it--is the form being submitted twice, perhaps--but shouldn't is recognize the duplicate username?

Here is my registration page (uses the built in registration wizard)

```
 Public Class Register
Inherits Page

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    RegisterUser.ContinueDestinationPageUrl = Request.QueryString("ReturnUrl")
End Sub

Protected Sub RegisterUser_CreatedUser(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles RegisterUser.CreatedUser
    FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(RegisterUser.UserName, createPersistentCookie:=False)


    Dim continueUrl As String = RegisterUser.ContinueDestinationPageUrl
    If Not OpenAuth.IsLocalUrl(continueUrl) Then
        continueUrl = "~/"
    End If

    Response.Redirect(continueUrl)
End Sub
```

Comment: Hard to help with the duplicate issue without seeing the code, but I have a hunch of what it might be(having had a similar issue in the past).

Comment: Added the code, but not sure if it helps. Using Azure SQL Server